# Numpy.savetxt ----- > How to save an array/matrix to a csv in python numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, csv

I have created a sort of matrix/data-table in python from multiple arrays containing various kinds of data, which looks like this in the variable view:

```
phones  starts  mids

sil 308000.0    308195.0

DH  308390.0    308410.0

AH0 308430.0    308445.0

B   308460.0    308525.0
```

These are three lists that I have combined using numpy.columnstack(). I am trying to output this table/matrix in the same format/structure but as a csv using numpy.savetxt. Is this possible given the different variable types in each row/column?

When I try to run :

```
np.savetxt('blue.txt', np.column_stack((phones, phone_starts, phone_mids)), ',', fmt="%s %f")
```

I get the error:

```
File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 4, in savetxt
TypeError: _savetxt_dispatcher() got multiple values for argument 'fmt'
```

I have also tried without the 'fmt' option and have gotten a similar error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at/show the result of the `column_stack`.  What is its `dtype` and `shape`?  My guess it is 2d with a string `dtype`. (with 3 columns).  In which case, I'd try `fmt='%s'`,  `savetxt` writes a `fmt % tuple(row)` for each row of the array.

Comment: The input order for `savetxt` is `filename, X, fmt, delimiter, ...`.  Use `delimiter=',', fmt='%s'.`

Comment: The type is 'Array of str256' of size (939,3)

Comment: thank you for your response

Comment: actually size is (939,2)

Answer (score 1):

Well, do you want to save np arrays to csv with labels? that is the type of work for which pandas were created.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {
"phone_starts": np.array([308000.0, 308390.0, 308430.0, 308460.0]),
"phone_mids": np.array([308195.0, 308410.0, 308445.0, 308525.0])
   }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=["sil", "DH", "AH0", "B"])
df.index.name = "Phone"
df.to_csv("blue.csv")
```

Comment: Hello thank you very much for responding. I got the sense that pandas might be necessary/more appropriate. i do want to save an array with labels so I will try implementing the code you suggested.

Comment: Am I able to create the data frame from the lists stored in variables or do I have to type them manuall? Because the portion above is only just a small part of the whole data

Comment: yes, for example, df = pd.DataFrame(list_arrays, columns=list_index, index=list_columns), if you create a list of np.arrays as data, I think DataFrame will infer it as rows, but it's possible to change that after. df = df.T